# How to get access token with MSAL

Tags: azure-ad-msal

I stitched together a lot of tutorials and documentation in order to get an access token with MSALin my JavaScript code. Here are the results of my research.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. npm install @azure/msal
2. import the necessary class from @azure/msal

   ```
       import {
         UserAgentApplication,
         AuthenticationParameters,
         Configuration,
       } from "@azure/msal";
   ```
3. Make the msal object

   ```
     const config: Configuration = {
       auth: {
         clientId: <client id - your app's client id>,
         authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantid>`,
         redirectUri: <the redirect Uri>,
       },
     };

     const params: AuthenticationParameters = {
       authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${Tenantid}`,
       scopes: [`${AppIDUri}/user_impersonation`],  <-- the API that you're trying to call
     };

     const myMSAL = new UserAgentApplication(config);
   ```
4. Get access token

   ```
    try {
     const login = await myMSAL.acquireTokenSilent(params);
     return login.accessToken;
   } catch (error) {
     await myMSAL.loginPopup(params);
     const login = await myMSAL.acquireTokenSilent(params);
     return login.accessToken;
   }
   ```

References:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-acquire-cache-tokens

[Azure/Msal authentication inside PowerApp Component Framework returns AADSTS50177 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63993949/azure-msal-authentication-inside-powerapp-component-framework-returns-aadsts5017)

Comment: Hello, any method to do this but with angular 16 and the MSAL v3 library? I tried this but it seems the library is no longer supported in new versions of angular

Answer (score 0):

### Approach 1

Only works if you actually do a redirect: next time, once logged in, you won't get your console message.

Based on this guide (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-spa-acquire-token?tabs=javascript2) I came up with the following

```js
this.msalsrv.handleRedirectObservable().subscribe( (redirectResponse) => {
  if(redirectResponse != null) {
    // Acquire token silent success
    let accessToken = redirectResponse.accessToken;
    // Call your API with token
    console.log("We got the token! hahaha: " + accessToken);
  }
})
```

### Approach 2

Made another try and figured out how to get the token. Make sure to use this code once the login processed has alredy been perfomed (for example if you're a page under MsalGuard).

```js
const accessTokenRequest = {
  scopes: ["user.read"],
  account: this.msalsrv.instance.getAllAccounts()[0],
};


this.msalsrv.acquireTokenSilent(accessTokenRequest).subscribe( (accessTokenReponse) => {
  if(accessTokenReponse != null) {
    // Acquire token silent success
    let accessToken = accessTokenReponse.accessToken;
    // Call your API with token
    console.log("We got the token! hahaha: " + accessToken);
  }
})
```

Notice this code just works.. you have to ensure what happens if your session has expired.